# Are hashes in the names Javascript and CSS files used for integrity checking?

Tags: javascript, css, filenames

Many websites use hashes in  Javacript and CSS file's name. For example, this page, as of writing, uses a file referred to with URL `.../stacks.min.js?v=b0f9a80d741d`. Other sites just place a short hash in the file's name: `main.abcd123.js`

- Is this used automated integrity checking? For example, when the browser loads `stacks.min.js?v=b0f9a80d741d`, does is verify that a hash or digest of this file matches `b0f9a...`.
- Does this pattern have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope its not for integrety checking. It for cache busting. Browsers cache static files. Everytime a new version of this script is uploaded the `?v=X` part changes (by the bundler/packager/...) so the browser thinks its a new file and downloades it again, instead of reading from the local cache.